# I can not access to my web site using weblogic and F5 load balaner

Tags: web, weblogic, load-balancing, f5

I have 3 weblogic application server in clustered state. I have access to my web site from each url. another person confige an F5 Load balancer for servers and say that all ip and port and other configures is ok. we test load balancer by an apache server on laptops, one of them is server and one of the is client and each of them is on each side of load balancer. It works ok and I can access to test application from load balancer ip and port. but I can not access to my application that has weblogic as application server. Why can't I access it? Can any help to me?

Comment: What is the error you see when you try to hit it? Is it a 404 or 503 or 303? Please provide more details as to the output of your request. Also are you using a browser to test the Load balancer? On the apaches, are you doing a GET and if so what flags? Are you ussing https or http?

Answer (score 0):

i set ip address of F5 loadbalancer as default gateway of server and now i can access to my website beyond the loadbalancer. is this solution is correct? why my connection is slower than connecting direct to server?